# Preventing losing focus when showing an element with jquery show

Tags: jquery, click, focus

I'll try the best to be as mutch clear as possible.

I've an element with a click handler attached via jquery, let's call this element "e1". When "e1" is clicked, the handler call a show() on another element, let's call this "e2".

The problem is that when i made a click, "e2" grab the focus. Instead of this, I want "e2" to show but "e1" to maintain the focus.

This is the click handler:

```
     $('#tabella_visite').on( 'click', '.selezione_calcolo_appuntamenti', function () {

            var elemento = $(this);
            var codice_visita = elemento.attr('codice_visita');

            elemento.toggleClass('bg-info selezionato');

            if(elemento.hasClass('selezionato')){
                $('#calcolo_appuntamento_massivo form').append('<input class="input_appuntamento_selezionato" id="input_appuntamento_selezionato_' + codice_visita + '" type="hidden" name="visite[]" value="' + codice_visita + '">');
            }else{
                $('#input_appuntamento_selezionato_' + codice_visita).remove();
            }

            gestioneTastoCalcoloAppuntamentoMassivo();

        } );
```

This is the function performing the show:

```
    function gestioneTastoCalcoloAppuntamentoMassivo(){

        var selezionati = $('.input_appuntamento_selezionato');

        $('#contatore_calcolo_appuntamento_massivo').html(selezionati.length);

        if(selezionati.length > 0){
            $('#calcolo_appuntamento_massivo').show(200);
        }else{
            $('#calcolo_appuntamento_massivo').hide(200);
        }
        
    }
```

(In other word I want the element with "selezione_calcolo_appuntamenti" class to maintain focus after the execution of "gestioneTastoCalcoloAppuntamentoMassivo" fired by clicking on it)

How can I maintain focus on "e1" while showing "e2" ?

Comment: `.show()` doesn't change the focus. My guess is that the `.html()` is replacing the element that had focus.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Sorry @Barmar for wasting your time. The problem was that the click event appens on a a tag with href="#". Default preventing was the simply solution, I feel really stupid. Sorry.